# Bresenham Line Drawing Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics

```
int Octet(double m, int Ax, int Ay, int Bx, int By)
{
    int octetNo = -1;
    double dx = Bx - Ax;
    double dy = By - Ay;

    //m = dy / dx;

    if(0<=m && m<=1)
    {
        if(Ax<Bx) octetNo = 1;
        else if(Bx<Ax) octetNo = 5;
    }
    else if(0>=m && m>=-1)
    {
        if(Bx<Ax) 
            octetNo = 4;
        else if(Ax<Bx) octetNo = 8;
    }
    else if(m>1)
    {
        if(Ay<By) octetNo = 2;
        else if(By<Ay) octetNo = 6;
    }
    else if(-1>m)
    {
        if(Ay<By) octetNo = 3;
        else if(By<Ay) octetNo = 7;
    }   

    return octetNo;
}

int NextDiIfDiIsGreaterThanOrEqualtoZero(double m, int di, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int di_plus_1 = -1;
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;

    int octet = Octet(m, x1, y1, x2, y2);

    switch(octet)
    {
    case 1:
    case 5:
        di_plus_1 = di - 2 * (dx - dy); 
        break;
    case 2:
    case 6:
        di_plus_1 = di + 2 * (dx - dy); 
        break;
    case 3:
    case 7:
        di_plus_1 = di - 2 * (dx + dy); 
        break;
    case 4:
    case 8:
        di_plus_1 = di + 2 * (dx + dy); 
        break;
    }

    return di_plus_1;
}

int NextDiIfDiIsSmallerThanZero(double m, int di, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int di_plus_1 = -1;
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;

    int octet = Octet(m, x1, y1, x2, y2);

    switch(octet)
    {
    case 1:
    case 5:
        di_plus_1 = di - 2 * dy; 
        break;
    case 2:
    case 6:
        di_plus_1 = di + 2 * dx; 
        break;
    case 3:
    case 7:
        di_plus_1 = di - 2 * dx; 
        break;
    case 4:
    case 8:
        di_plus_1 = di + 2 * dy; 
        break;
    }

    return di_plus_1;
}

int InitialValueOfDi(double m, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int init_di = -1;
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;

    int octet = Octet(m, x1, y1, x2, y2);

    switch(octet)
    {
    case 1:
    case 5:
        init_di = dx - 2 * dy; 
        break;
    case 2:
    case 6:
        init_di = 2 * dx - dy; 
        break;
    case 3:
    case 7:
        init_di = (-2) * dx - dy; 
        break;
    case 4:
    case 8:
        init_di = 2 * dy + dx; 
        break;
    }

    return init_di;
}

void BresLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int color)
{
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    double m = (double)dy/(double)dx;
    int di = InitialValueOfDi(m, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    int limit = ((abs(dx)>abs(dy))?abs(dx):abs(dy))/2;
    int x = x1;
    int y = y1;

    for(int i=0 ; i<=limit; i++)
    {
        PlotPixel(x, y, color);

        if(di>=0)
        {
            di = NextDiIfDiIsGreaterThanOrEqualtoZero(m, di, x1, y1, x2, y2);
            y++;            
        }
        else
        {
            di = NextDiIfDiIsSmallerThanZero(m, di, x1, y1, x2, y2);            
        }       
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems okay, but this question could be made better with some textual explanation. Please take a moment to read: [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions).

Answer (score 5):

> **Disclaimer:** I know **nothing** of C++, but I'll help you as much as I can.

---

Overall, your code looks good. A+ for readability! Probably a missing spot somewhere, but no biggy. Still, your code is easy to read and follow.

---

On your `BresLine()`, you have this:

```
int dy = y2 - y1;
int dx = x2 - x1;
double m = (double)dy/(double)dx;
[...]
int limit = ((abs(dx)>abs(dy))?abs(dx):abs(dy))/2;
```

You could try to store that `abs()` somewhere, to shave on re-calling it.

---

You have the functions `NextDiIfDiIsGreaterThanOrEqualtoZero()` and `NextDiIfDiIsSmallerThanZero()`. They have **giant** names. And the code is almost the same. I suggest the following:

```
int NextDi(double m, int di, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int di_plus_1 = -1;
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;

    int octet = Octet(m, x1, y1, x2, y2);

    switch(octet)
    {
        case 1:
        case 5:
            di_plus_1 = di - 2 * (di > 0 ? dx - dy : dy); 
            break;
        case 2:
        case 6:
            di_plus_1 = di + 2 * (di > 0 ? dx - dy : dx); 
            break;
        case 3:
        case 7:
            di_plus_1 = di - 2 * (di > 0 ? dx - dy : dx); 
            break;
        case 4:
        case 8:
            di_plus_1 = di + 2 * (di > 0 ? dx - dy : dy); 
            break;
    }



    return di_plus_1;
}
```

It isn't the prettiest thing on Earth, but may work for you. To call it, you don't have to change anything! Just remove that `if` on `BresLine`. With some bitwise operations, you can cut down this code by a lot!

---

If you see something innacurate, please tell me. I haven't touched on the remaining functions, but I'm specially worried about the `Octet` function.

Comment: just now I found that my implementation doesn't work properly.

Comment: @anonymous finding bugs is part of what's possible to find in a peer review. Feel free to post a self-review to point out the bug. The "broken code is off-topic" rule is only there to avoid "please help me debug my code" questions; every now and then reviewers *do* find bugs in OP's code; answers don't make a question off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

## Bugs

Given these lines:

> ```
> int limit = ((abs(dx)>abs(dy))?abs(dx):abs(dy))/2;
> int x = x1;
> int y = y1;
> for(int i=0 ; i<=limit; i++)
> {
>     PlotPixel(x, y, color);
>     if(di>=0)
>     {
>         di = something;
>         y++;            
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         di = something;           
>     }       
>     x++;
> }
> ```

I can immediately deduce the following problems:

1. Your program will only draw about half of the line requested because it draws `limit+1` number of pixels, and `limit` is half the length of the longest dimension.
2. Your program can't draw vertical lines because each loop increments `x` unconditionally.  This also means that it can't possibly draw any line steeper than 45 degrees.
3. Your program only has `x++` and not `x--`.  But if `x2` is smaller than `x1`, then you are drawing in the wrong direction.  Same thing for `y`.

Further investigation showed that the program doesn't handle horizontal lines correctly either (`y` gets incremented on the first iteration).

These bugs seem like they should have been pretty obvious if you actually ran the code and plotted the results.  I suggest spending a lot more time testing.